# How to open p.stdout after using p.communicate()

Tags: python, powershell

I have just figured out that when I use p.communicate(), it will close the stdout and stdin etc..., is there a way to prevent this or just reopen stdout because I want to be able to keep doing p.stdout.readline() after using p.communicate()

Comment: You can't, communicate waits until process terminates(and it reads from stdout until EOF anyways).

Comment: is there another way i can send an input just like using communicate but in a way that wont have to wait until the process ends

Comment: p.stdin.write()?

Comment: doesn't seem to work